# VGG Image Annotator can't import annotations from CSV file

Tags: computer-vision

I've been using VGG Image Annotator to annotate images using the local version (via-3.0.9) from GitLab.  I've exported the images to a CSV file but after rebooting the computer and going back to VIA I'm not able to import the CSV file because it only supports JSON format for annotation imports.  I've also tried the online VIA app which does allow CSV import but the first time I tried it, there was some error about a missing header and subsequent import attempts do nothing at all.

The export looks like:

```
# Exported using VGG Image Annotator (http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/via)                                                                                        
# Notes:                                                                                             
# - spatial_coordinates of [2,10,20,50,80] denotes a rectangle (shape_id=2) of size 50x80 placed at (10,20)
# - temporal coordinate of [1.349,2.741] denotes a temporal segment from time 1.346 sec. to 2.741 sec.
# - temporal coordinate of [4.633] denotes a still video frame at 4.633 sec.                         
# - metadata of {""1"":""3""} indicates attribute with id "1" set to an attribute option with id "3" 
# SHAPE_ID = {"POINT":1,"RECTANGLE":2,"CIRCLE":3,"ELLIPSE":4,"LINE":5,"POLYLINE":6,"POLYGON":7,"EXTREME_RECTANGLE":8,"EXTREME_CIRCLE":9}
# FLAG_ID = {"RESERVED_FOR_FUTURE":1}                                                                
# ATTRIBUTE = {}                                                                                     
# CSV_HEADER = metadata_id,file_list,flags,temporal_coordinates,spatial_coordinates,metadata         
"1_auhS9dP3","[""train_in_9344_256.png""]",0,"[]","[6,13.474,1.078,12.665,68.985,15.629,98.897,14.552,194.829,21.019,203.992,12.935,213.962,12.935,221.777,19.402,247.107]"
"1_2CrCZ69X","[""train_in_9344_256.png""]",0,"[]","[6,127.731,1.617,128.269,246.029,128.539,253.575]","{}"
"1_oGrbStD2","[""train_in_9344_256.png""]",0,"[]","[6,194.56,253.844,188.901,210.728,179.469,147.402]","{}"
```

Is there anyway to import this back into VIA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of loading the csv file from the **Project** menu, Try to use this option:

1. Go to the **Annotations** menu
2. Then select **Import Annotations (from csv)**
   Your images will apppear then you can continue working from where you left off